# SSH websetup -y "command not found" - Putty (Mac)

Tags: command-line, ssh, terminal, putty

Our university have given us webspace to host our webpages this term. The instructions given include using SSH client Putty to connect to the server and run the command **websetup -y** however this is being returned as command not found.

I'm on macOS Mojave and I've put my files in the public_html folder using my FTP client (Transmit). I'm also aware SSH is built in to Terminal and can successful connect to the server that way.

I tried the [MacPorts](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/mac/) version of Putty just in case there was anything different about using Putty itself and can successfully connect however I get the same 'command not found' when trying websetup.

My understanding is the Putty is just to connect to server so I feel it's unnecessary when I can use SSH in the Terminal, however the site itself is unreachable: curl finds a 302 temporary redirect to a 404 page.
[curl 302 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nydIT.png)

I've been able to find very little about the **websetup** command online so i'm not entirely sure what it's intended for? I got the impression that it may be to do with permissions however even when I (temporarily) chmod to 777 the site is still unreachable.

If it helps, my $PATH variable is currently set to:
[$PATH variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ZNS.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is this an issue on my University's end rather than mine?

Comment: You are saying you can log on to the server using ssh but then when you try to run a command it says "not found"?  That is **websetup** is a command you are supposed to run on the server after connecting?  It would be more interesting to see the path once you are connected rather than the path on your Macbook if so.  It sounds like problem at the University end really.

Comment: Yes, the guide we have says to connect via SSH using Putty (but I can connect successfully using Putty or Terminal) then run the websetup command. The path being connected to via SSH is #######@unix.city.ac.uk where ####### is my username and city.ac.uk is the University's domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds VERY much like this "websetup" command is a script/program custom to your university - it is certainly not a "standard" way of setting up hosting on a Unix based system.

The issue is not putty or ssh - these simply provide a remote console/terminal.

In short, this "websetup" command is not in the path or does not exist, and is most likely a problem with the university setup - that is to say that the issue is on the Universities end rather then yours - so  I'd query someone there.

You might be able to find the command by using "find / -type f -name "websetup", but I'm not sure I would advise it as this could take significant resources on the server and may be undesirable.

You might also want to try (at least temporarily) changing the permissions on the public_html directory and files to world readable - its possible this is not a default, and a cause of your issue, but I suspect this is a bit unlikely.

Comment: Thanks David, what's strange is I found another university with a tutorial saying to run the same command but I can't find any documentation on it. As you say, it might be a custom script and it's not impossible that it'd be available to multiple universities.

I tried temporarily making public_html and all files bellow world readable without success. I've reached out to the university on this. I'm glad it sounds like i'm not missing the obvious.

Comment: *Update* : Decided to have a go with the find command and did actually find both websetup and run-websetup. The former is a perl script and the latter a shell script but no further forward than that. I'll see what our IT services have to say and update my question as soon as I get answer.

Comment: The name "websetup" is hardly unique - I'd probably call a script to do some web set-up "websetup".  I can see a couple (Cisco and calpoly.edu) on Google but I think you are correct - ask IT.  @davidgo is right - it is not putty issue - you can use putty or "ssh" (from terminal in either macOS or Windows) and you should see this command if it is in the path you get after log-on.

Comment: Many, many thanks for the help with this both. It turns out it was a permissions issue with a hidden file in the root directory that did not have execute rights. All fixed now.